# CSV Blob Sink - Skip Writing File when 0 Rows Present

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

This is a relatively simple problem with (I'm hoping) a similarly-simple solution.

In my ADF ETLs, any time there's a known and expected yet unrecoverable row-based error, I don't want my full ETL to fail. Instead, I'd rather pipe those rows off to a log, which I can then pick up at the end of the ETL for manual inspection. To do this, I use conditional splits.

Most of the time, there shouldn't be any rows like this. When this is the case, I don't want my blob sink to write a file. However, the current behavior writes a file no matter what -- it's just that the file only contains the table header.

Is there a way to skip writing anything to a blob sink when there are no input rows?

Edit: Somehow I forgot to specify -- I'm specifically referring to a Mapping Data Flow with a blob sink.

Comment: What type of activity is your ETL? Is it a Copy activity? Can you not use the OnSuccess condition of an activity?

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't specify -- I'm talking about a Mapping Data Flow with a blob sink.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lookup activity(don't check first row only) to get all your table data firstly. Then use If condition to check the count of Lookup activity's output. If its count > 0, execute next activity(or data flow).